# How to make a array from another array with grouping data based on id .?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, express

I have an array object as follows,

```js
const data = [
   {
      "order_id":"ORDCUTHIUJ",
      "branch_code":"MVPA",
      "total_amt":199500,
      "product_details":[
         {
            "image":"CC252.jpg",
            "cate":"Mobile Accessories"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "order_id":"ORHOGFD79L",
      "branch_code":"PBVR",
      "total_amt":325880,
      "product_details":[
         {
            "image":"1617382086515.jpg",
            "cate":"Mobile Accessories"
         },
         {
            "image":"1617382322759.jpg",
            "cate":"Mobile Accessories"
         },
         {
            "image":"CC251.jpg",
            "cate":"Mobile Accessories"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "order_id":"ORIYDJLYSJ",
      "branch_code":"MVPA",
      "total_amt":1549500,
      "product_details":[
         {
            "image":"CC250.jpg",
            "cate":"Mobile Accessories"
         },
         {
            "image":"CC256.jpg",
            "cate":"Mobile Accessories"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

what I want to achieve is to build a new array based on this, but I want to group the data with the same branch code under one object.

**Expected Output:**

```
const newData = 
[
  {
    MVPA: [
      {
        order_id: 'ORIYDJLYSJ',
        (otherdetails)
      },
      {
        order_id: 'ORDCUTHIUJ',
        (otherdetails
      }
    ]
  },
  PBVR: [
    {
      order_id: 'ORHOGFD79L',
      (otherdetails)
    }
  ]
```

can someone help me out on how to achieve this.? I want a general solution, bcoz this data could be longer than this when I get from DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Array.reduce.

`data.reduce((o, a) => (o[a.branch_code] = [ ...(o[a.branch_code] || []), a], o), {})`

Answer (score 0):

First create an object which collects data with branch_code.

```
const obj = data.reduce((map,obj)=>{
     if(obj.branch_code in map){
       map[obj.branch_code].push({...obj})
     }
     else{
      map[obj.branch_code]=[{...obj}]
     }
    return map
},{})
```

This gives

```
{MVPA: Array(2), PBVR: Array(1)}
```

Then,map over the keys  of the above object to create your required array.

```
const result = Object.keys(obj).map(key => ({[key]:
[...obj[key]]}))

console.log('result',result)
```

This gives

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0: {MVPA: Array(2)}
1: {PBVR: Array(1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const uniqueBranchCode = [...new Set(data.map(i => i.branch_code))] // Get unique branch_code

const newData = uniqueBranchCode
.map(order => data.filter(orderSpecific => orderSpecific.branch_code === order)) // Filter to group together by branch_code
.map(item => ({[item[0].branch_code]: item})) // Assign key and return elements
```

```js
const data = [
   {
      "order_id":"ORDCUTHIUJ",
      "branch_code":"MVPA",
      "total_amt":199500,
      "product_details":[
         {
            "image":"CC252.jpg",
            "cate":"Mobile Accessories"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "order_id":"ORHOGFD79L",
      "branch_code":"PBVR",
      "total_amt":325880,
      "product_details":[
         {
            "image":"1617382086515.jpg",
            "cate":"Mobile Accessories"
         },
         {
            "image":"1617382322759.jpg",
            "cate":"Mobile Accessories"
         },
         {
            "image":"CC251.jpg",
            "cate":"Mobile Accessories"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "order_id":"ORIYDJLYSJ",
      "branch_code":"MVPA",
      "total_amt":1549500,
      "product_details":[
         {
            "image":"CC250.jpg",
            "cate":"Mobile Accessories"
         },
         {
            "image":"CC256.jpg",
            "cate":"Mobile Accessories"
         }
      ]
   }
]

const uniqueBranchCode = [...new Set(data.map(i => i.branch_code))]

const newData = uniqueBranchCode
.map(order => data.filter(orderSpecific => orderSpecific.branch_code === order))
.map(item => ({[item[0].branch_code]: item}))

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

```js
const data =[{"order_id":"ORDCUTHIUJ","branch_code":"MVPA","total_amt":199500,"product_details":[{"image":"CC252.jpg","cate":"Mobile Accessories"}]},{"order_id":"ORHOGFD79L","branch_code":"PBVR","total_amt":325880,"product_details":[{"image":"1617382086515.jpg","cate":"Mobile Accessories"},{"image":"1617382322759.jpg","cate":"Mobile Accessories"},{"image":"CC251.jpg","cate":"Mobile Accessories"}]},{"order_id":"ORIYDJLYSJ","branch_code":"MVPA","total_amt":1549500,"product_details":[{"image":"CC250.jpg","cate":"Mobile Accessories"},{"image":"CC256.jpg","cate":"Mobile Accessories"}]}];

const result = data.reduce((acc, {order_id, branch_code, product_details}) => {
  acc[branch_code] ??= {[branch_code]: []};
  acc[branch_code][branch_code].push({order_id, product_details});
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help ^^! @Thorin

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = {}

function comp(x) {
const f1 = data.filter(function (i) {
    return i.branch_code === x
})

return f1
}

for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
obj[`${data[i].branch_code}`] = comp(data[i].branch_code)
}

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: Call your function inside for loop